# Enlarge time series and fill with -9999 R

Tags: r, merge, time-series

I run am model from 2007-01-01 00 to 2013-12-31 23. Not all my observations are that long, they start later and/or end earlier. In that case I want to fill in -9999 values.
**I have:**

```
[1,] "2003 09 01 01" "0"                  
[2,] "2003 09 01 02" "0"                  
[3,] "2003 09 01 03" "0"                  
[4,] "2003 09 01 04" "0" [1,] "2003 09 01 04" "0" 
[5,] "2003 09 01 05" "0" [2,] "2003 09 01 05" "0" 
[6,] "2003 09 01 06" "0" [3,] "2003 09 01 06" "0"
```

**This shall result in**

```
[1,] "2003 09 01 01" "-9999"
[2,] "2003 09 01 02" "-9999"
[3,] "2003 09 01 03" "-9999"
[4,] "2003 09 01 04" "0"
[5,] "2003 09 01 05" "0"
[6,] "2003 09 01 06" "0"
```

My reference date column is created as following:

```
library(gtools)
library(xts)
library(hydroTSM)
hips <- hip(from="2007-01-01 01",to="2014-12-31 23")
long.date <- strptime(x=hips, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
long.date.col <- cbind(format.POSIXlt(x=long.date,format="%Y %m %d %H"))
head(long.date.col)
```

I have to specify a certain format for the "dates" so this column is of class character eventually.

Now I want to merge it somehow, but merge doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thankful for help!
Best regards
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`short` is the name of your 2nd matrix):

```
res <- as.matrix(merge(long.date.col, short, all.x = T))
res[is.na(res)] <- "-9999"
```